# Problem w/ Azure Cognitive Search Vector Search + Filter

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, vector-search

The Azure Cognitive Search vector documention says: "Filtered vector search. A query request can include a vector query and a filter expression. Filters apply to text and numeric fields, and are useful for including or excluding search documents based on filter criteria. Although a vector field isn't filterable itself, you can set up a filterable text or numeric field. The search engine processes the filter first, reducing the surface area of the search corpus before running the vector query."

In my tests the filter can affect the vector search such that the k is not respected.

I have a populated index with 5 docs that match the filter but with a k=5, i sometimes only get 1 or 2 documents back (there are many docs that don't match the filter) -- if I increase k to 500+, I then get back 5 documents. this isn't what one would expect if filtering was applyed before the vector search.  Is filtering, in fact, applied after the vector search?

Answer (score 3):

This behavior stems from the time that the filter is applied. The current behavior for filtering with HNSW is "post filtering", which means the set of `k`-NN is retrieved and then combined with the set of filtered results. For highly selective filters, this can cause the result set to have too few results that satisfy the filter. For low values of k, this would reduce the size of the result set on which filtering is applied. In both scenarios, filtering can cause fewer than k results.

You can either increase the requested k value to have a higher set of candidate results before applying the filter, or wait for support of "pre-filtering" natively.

Prefiltering is now available per the 2023-10-01-Preview REST APIs. The beta Azure SDK libraries are in process of being updated and finalized. Prefiltering requires a new index, so if the index is older than Oct 1, you would need a new one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/vector-search-how-to-query?tabs=query-2023-10-01-Preview%2Cfilter-2023-10-01-Preview#vector-query-with-filter

We'll improve the docs to explain this behavior since the current wording of that paragraph is inaccurate. Specifically, this is incorrect for post-filtering: _The search engine processes the filter first, reducing the surface area of the search corpus before running the vector query.

Comment: Edited to add, the docs should be updated now.

Comment: Edit to add comment that pre-filter is available now for new indexes created after ~Oct 1, 2023